# вывод what() исключения на консоль

Tags: c++, visual-studio, исключения, devc++

```
#include <stdexcept>
int main()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Error");
}
```

Почему данная программа в `DevC++` выводит на консоль `Error`, а в `Visual Studio 2015` - нет? Может какой параметр надо изменить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Потому что разные реализации класса runtime_error.

Если вам нужно, что бы ошибка выводилась в консоль, оформляйте ошибку так:

`std::cerr << std::runtime_error("Error").what() << std::endl;`. И не забудьте подключить заголовок: `#include <iostream>`

Так же вы можете расширить `std::exception` и написать свой вывод в консоль:

```
class customError: public std::exception
{
    public:
    customError(const std::exception& e)
    {
        OutputDebugString(e.what());
        OutputDebugString("\n");
        if (1) // avoids C4702 (unreachable code)
            throw e;
    }
};
```

Использование:

`throw customError(std::runtime_error("Error"));`

Answer (score 1):

Давайте еще раз посмотрим на код:

```
int main()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Error");
}
```

Итак, у вас есть **неперехваченное** исключение. Которое вообще никто не перехватывает и не обрабатывает. *Кто* же, по-вашему, должен вывести о нем сообщение?

*Среда* может перехватить и вывести сообщение (чего никто не требует), но совершенно *не обязана* это делать.

Лучшее, что вы можете сделать - если не перехватывать исключение - это установить свою функцию завершения, вызываемую при неперехваченном исключении, типа

```
void Quit()
{
    cout << "Uncaught exception\n";
    exit(1);
};

int main()
{
    set_terminate(Quit);
    throw std::runtime_error("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Visual Studio не печатает содержимое, которое может быть получено из `what()` при падении? С чего Вы вообще взяли, что она должна это делать? Видимо, в DevC++ решили, что это полезно и сделали эту функциональность. В Visual Studio такого нет и, честно говоря, не вижу в этом никакой пользы.